# Getting ERROR 000840 from arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000840

I am trying to select layer by attribute and for that, I am using `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management` function . My command is as follows:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(union, 'NEW_SELECTION', '"gridcode" =1 AND "area" >=25000000*0.4')
```

Here, `union` is the shapefile, from which I need to select layers by attribute.  My SQL query is `"gridcode" =1 AND "area" >=25000000*0.4`

I am getting the following error:

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. The value
>   cannot be a feature class ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster
>   Layer. ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer. Failed to
>   execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).`

Comment: couldn't you test `"area" >= 10000000`?

Comment: yes i just changed it but still it gives error

Comment: Try creating a feature layer using MakeFeatureLayer, and pass this to SelectLayerByAttributes.

Comment: We'd need to see more of your script to know. Whatever `union` is appears to be the problem. It's not a _layer_ that the tool wants.

Comment: Bring in the make feature layer and select layer by attribute tools into ModelBuilder, set up everything in there and run it.  If it runs successfully in ModelBuilder select Model>Export>To Python Script...  You may then evaluate these two statements in python and see what was needed to get it to work.

Comment: @KHibma union is my grid shapefile

Comment: @lsr729 ok - but knowing how shapefile is referenced is important. As mentioned 2x now, using Make Feature Layer will probably "fix" it as your reference is shapefile reference is _probably_ to a path on disk, not as a layer.

Comment: Yes it worked after making a layer first. Thank

Comment: You can do a self-answer here. Add the code you used to "make it work" and accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select on a feature class when it should be a feature layer. Use [MakeFeatureLayer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) to create a layer then pass this to SelectLayerByAttributes:

> Creates a feature layer from an input feature class or layer file

(It is also possible to use a where_clause in MakeFeatureLayer and then there is no need for SelectLayerByAttributes.)